# Spring Boot AccessDecisionVoter custom Unauthorized message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a custom *AccessDecisionVoter* for a custom Annotation, which restricts the access to certain methods, based on the scopes provided in the Annotation. This works without a problem, but the response I get when the Authentication is missing the scope is always the same and I am looking for a way to customize this. Thank you in advance.

**ScopeVoter**

```
public class ScopeVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<MethodInvocation> {

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        //custom logic here which decides to grant or deny the access. Here the message should be customized.
    }
```

**AuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEntryPointImp implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

This is where the response is generated and I am trying to get the custom message to this
AuthenticationEntryPoint.

**HTTPSecurety Configuration**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

authenticationEntryPoint() is the described class above.

PS: I also want to get a custom message from the authFilter() to the EntryPoint.

**EDIT:**
It was pointed out to me that this might not be possible, but if not in the AuthenticationEntryPoint there must be another place.
And I also want to display a custom message from the AuthenticationFilter in the AuthenticationEntryPoint, which definitely gets called when the auth fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if use is authenticated successfully, and then the voter is denied, you can configure your **AccessDeniedHandler**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    response.getWriter().println(accessDeniedException.getMessage());
                }
            }).authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    
        http.addFilterBefore(authFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

then in **ScopeVoter**, you can throw **AccessDeniedException** by yourself

```
public class ScopeVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<MethodInvocation> {

@Override
public int vote(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
    //if the logic is not met, throw it directly
    throw new AccessDeniedException("your customize message is here");
}
```

Comment: I cannot throw an exception in the vote method, since there are none on the method signature.

Comment: AccessDeniedException is a RuntimeException, so no need method signature

Comment: There are two implementations of `AccessDeniedException` which It didn't work... Perfect, this solved my problem on how to get the custom message there. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think it is impossible to do this, because **AuthenticationEntryPoint.commence()** and **AccessDecisionVoter.voter()** is mutual exclusion, when the authentication is failure, the voter will not be called, when the authentication is success, the commence will not be called()

Comment: Ok, I see that now, but if not in then AuthenticationEntryPoint there must be a location where I can customize the "Forbidden" message.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

For the customized error response part of your question: I have configured `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint` so that it invokes my general exception handler defined with @ControllerAdvice.

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Source code is available [here](https://github.com/nagypet/wstemplate).

Comment: I think this will just shift my problem to another class, since I am already able to customize the message in `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. 

The problem is getting the data why the auth failed from the `AuthenticationFilter` which is a `OncePerRequestFilter` to the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`,

Comment: >>> The problem is getting the data why the auth failed from the AuthenticationFilter. The reason should be in ex. You must ensure, that in the `OncePerRequestFilter` only subclasses of `AuthenticationException` is thrown, otherwise your `AuthenticationEntryPoint` will not be called.

Comment: I actually thought about that but even if I trow a 'AuthenticationException' the exception is not caught, and I get a stack trace in the console and an empty response.